# angular show snackbar after save

Tags: angular

It is hard to formulate this question, so the title is misleading. But the scenario is as follows.

I have a list page say `/items` and an `/items/:id` page which is an edit page. After user goes to `/items/:id` can edit the item, or just cancel and go back to the `/items` page.

When the user clicks the save button, I save the item, and navigate back to `/items/` page. In this case I want to show a snackbar to tell the user that the item is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the redirect part and show a message using **[`Snackbar`](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples)** as follows,

```
this.snackBar.open('Item edited successfully', 'ok', {
      duration: 4000
 });
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsy4yd?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: But then how do I go back. I want to go back to the list page, THEN show the snackbar

Comment: ok in that case you need to place the snackbar on the list page